# Passing Scanner object as a constructor parameter to the UserInterface class

Tags: java, oop, java.util.scanner

While I was watching a youtube video on how to seperate UserInterface from the program logic, the guy on the video passed the scanner class object as a parameter to the UserInterface class's constructor from the main method. Like this:

```
public class UserInterface {
TodoList list;
Scanner input;

UserInterface(TodoList list,Scanner input){
    this.list=list;
    
    this.input=input;
    
}
}
```

My question is that why didn't he create a Scanner class object in the UserInterface class instead of passing the Scanner object as a parameter from Main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Scanner is a resource. It's a really weird resource; **normally** resources are for a fleeting resource (as in, the idea is to stop needing that resource well before the application exits entirely), and one amongst an entire class (as in, you can open 1 file, or a million. The concept 'file' is a multitude; you can have many files). System.in is weird; You don't want to close it, and there is only ever one.

That makes it a weird resource.

Nevertheless, it is one, and resources are best treated as singular entities. You wouldn't want to create 2 separate file readers simultaneously. For the same reason you don't want 2 scanners. Scanners can (and do!) cache, so if you call, say, `.hasNextInt()` on one scanner and then call `.next()` in the other, things become weird, because scanner wasn't designed to do that.

Let me try to put it this way: `System.in` is a global constant. Therefore any scanner that consumes System.in should also be, because it is specified as a thing that may cache things.

Separately, this also opens the door to allowing your `UserInterface` class to operate on different input. Maybe you want to, someday, take input from an internet connection, or a batch file with a series of commands in it. Or, even simpler, you want to write an automated test.

`Scanner` doesn't inherently mean: "From standard input". You can make a Scanner out of many things: Files, network connections, hardcoded strings, anything you want, really.